# how to convert void* to size_t?

Tags: c++, parameters, casting, pthreads

I have a timer thread and function for this thread and must pass a parameter size_t to the function.

```
void* global::timer_event::entry_point(void* n)
{
    namespace N = global::utils;
    struct timeval tv;
    size_t* s = (size_t*)n;     
    N::set_timer(tv, *s);
    while(1)
    {
        if (N::check_timer(tv, *s) == 1)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&set_queue_mutex);
            N::print_queue(q);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&set_queue_mutex);
        }
    }
}

void global::timer_event::run(size_t n)
{
    pthread_create(&m_t, 0, &entry_point, (void*)n);
}
```

But the program will crash on the line  `N::set_timer(tv, *s);` 
that is, when you use  *s. How to well make this conversion ?

Comment: C++ threads are a lot easier. You can just pass them a lambda `[n]{entry_point(n);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first cast is *from* `size_t`.

Then you cast *to* `size_t*`.

That is obviously wrong.

Cast it back to `size_t` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_create(&m_t, 0, &entry_point, (void*)n);
```

You pass the value of n to the threadFunc.
For example, if n = 0 (or other value),in these statements:

```
size_t* s = (size_t*)n;     
N::set_timer(tv, *s);
```

*(s = 0) ==> access the address 0x0 (or other protected memory)==>access violation at address ==> crash~~BOOM~~

Answer (score 0):

When you create the thread, you pass the variable `n` *by value*, but you use it as a *pointer* in the thread function. You need to cast it as *not* a pointer in the thread function.

Comment: The second solution would require copying the value, as the initial value `size_t n` goes out of scope when the function `run` returns.